# How to limit the selection from check boxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code with the check boxes:

```
  <% @roles.each do |role| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'role', role %> 
    <%=h role %></p>
  <% end %></p>
```

I want to limit the selction options from these boxes, so that only one at the same time can be selected.

And only if a second one will be selected, should the first one unselected and the second one selected.

Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at [`radio_button_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag).  Looks like this is what you're looking for.